# How to upload the file using angular and express js?

Tags: angular, express

I have tried to upload the files using middleware but not getting the value in any of these req.files, req.file or req,body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me:-

upload.component.html

```
    <form #uploadForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="upload(uploadForm.value)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
```

upload.component.ts

```
        // On file Select
      onChange(event:any) {
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
      }

     //on Sumbit Function
    sync upload(data:any){

    // Create form data
    const formData = new FormData(); 
        
    // Store form name as "file" with file data
    formData.append("file", this.file, this.file.name);
    
    console.log(this.file.name, this.file, formData);

    await this.http.post(this.baseUrl, formData).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('response received is ', response);
  })
```

and in server-side or index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));


//middleware
const multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
const multipartMiddleware = multipart({
    uploadDir: './upload'
});
app.use(cors());

app.post('/upload',multipartMiddleware,(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({
        'message': 'File uploaded successfully.'
    });
    console.log(req.files.file.path);
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);
});
```